# printf issue with array

Tags: php

So i have a problem with taking an array and looping through the values and outputing with a foreach statement.

**code**

```
<?php
$example = array("test" => "hello world" );

foreach ($example as $arr) {
  printf("<p>what do you have to say for yourself?</p><p>%s!</p>",$arr["test"]);
}

?>
```

**hoping to get the output:**

what do you have to say for yourself?

hello world!

**Instead get**

what do you have to say for yourself?

h!

why just the single character?

Any help would be great

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your foreach loop is already going through the values of the array, so don't reference the value again using the key:

```
<?php
$example = array("test" => "hello world" );

foreach ($example as $key => $val) {
  printf("<p>what do you have to say for yourself?</p><p>%s!</p>",$val);
}

?>
```

From your other example in the comments, you would not be able to use a loop because the placements are very specific.  Instead reference each value specifically without a loop:

```
$example = array(
    "first" => "Bob", 
    "last" => "Smith", 
    "address" => "123 Spruce st"
);
printf("<p>my name is %s %s and i live at %s</p>", 
    $example['first'], 
    $example['last'], 
    $example['address']
);
```

Comment: awesome, but what if i have more than one key => value in the array?

Comment: @danferth: the foreach will go through every key/value pair in the array and run printf for every one.

Comment: @MattS `printf("<p>what do you have to say for yourself?</p><p>%s %s</p>",$val);`  is giving me errors though.  the example is a simplified version.  in reality it would be a large array for contacts.  And a database is out of the question on this project.

Comment: @danferth: Then you'll have to provide a more detailed example because this one gives no errors.  The size of the array is irrelevant unless you're running out of memory.

Comment: @MattS `$example = array("first" => "Bob", "last" => "Smith", "address" => "123 Spruce st" );

foreach ($example as $key => $val) {
  printf("<p>my name is %s %s and i live at %s</p>",$val);
}`

Comment: @MattS there will be more than one contact would i not have to use the `foreach` as the below example is only outputting the last array
`$example = array("first" => "Bob", "last" => "Smith", "address" =>     "123 Spruce st" );


$example = array("first" => "Sara", "last" => "Blask", "address" => "5678 Maple ct" );


foreach ($example as $key => $val) {


  printf("<p>hello my name is %s %s and i live at %s</p>",$example['first'],$example['last'], $example['address']);


}`

Comment: @danferth: Then you're still not providing a complete example with exactly what your data structure will look like. So I can't give you an answer. Are they separate arrays?  Nested arrays?  Please open another question with a COMPLETE accurate example and link to it.

Comment: @MattS here is the link to the new question [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12375983/looping-through-arrays-with-foreach-staement)  Sorry for not explaining in more detail from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps looking at it this way will help;

```
<?php 
$example = array("test" => "hello world", "foo" => "bar"); 

foreach ($example as $key => $val) { 
# option 1
    echo "<p>what do you have to say for yourself?</p><p>$key => $val</p>"; 
# option 2
    echo "<p>what do you have to say for yourself?</p><p>$key => $example[$key]</p>"; 
} 
?>
```

Once you see how it iterates through, you can put your statement back into printf() or do whatever with the variables.

Note that if you have multidimensional arrays, you can refer to the next level of the array by addressing the key;

Answer (score 0):

Looping over your associative array is putting a value in `$arr` each iteration. When you try to index into $arr you're actually indexing into a string, hence the single character.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach assumes there is more than one element in the array.  If not just echo out the element like echo $example['test']; No need for a looping construct.  If more than one element:

```
$example = array('text'=>"what do you have to say for yourself?",'test' => "hello world" );

print_r($example);

foreach ($example as $value)  
printf("<p>%s!</p>",$value);
```

foreach is assigning the value of an array element to a variable called $value on each loop. Make sense?