# looping through arrays with foreach statement

Tags: php, arrays

I have a list of arrays and need them to output with a printf statement

```
<?php
$example = array("first" => "Bob", "last" => "Smith", "address" => "123 Spruce st" );
$example = array("first" => "Sara", "last" => "Blask", "address" => "5678 Maple ct" );

foreach ($example as $key => $val) {
  printf("<p>hello my name is %s %s and i live at %s</p>",$example['first'],$example['last'], $example['address']);
}

?>
```

The above just outputs the last array, i need it to loop through all of the arrays and produce a `<p>` with the supplied `key => value` combinations.  this is only a simplified example as the real world code will be more complex in the outputted `html`

I tried

```
foreach ($example as $arr){
printf("<p>hello my name is %s %s and i live at %s</p>",$arr['first'],$arr['last'], $arr['address']);
}
```

but it only outputs a single character for each `key => value`

Comment: You're declaring `$example` twice - the second one will over-write the first one. That definitely won't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// Declare $example as an array, and add arrays to it
$example = array();
$example[] = array("first" => "Bob", "last" => "Smith", "address" => "123 Spruce st" );
$example[] = array("first" => "Sara", "last" => "Blask", "address" => "5678 Maple ct" );

// Loop over each sub-array
foreach( $example as $val) {
    // Access elements via $val
    printf("<p>hello my name is %s %s and i live at %s</p>",$val['first'],$val['last'], $val['address']);
}
```

You can see from [this demo](http://viper-7.com/aKgniZ) that it prints:

```
hello my name is Bob Smith and i live at 123 Spruce st
hello my name is Sara Blask and i live at 5678 Maple ct
```

Comment: Awesome that's what i was missing declaring $example as an array! thank you. and +1 for the demo!

Comment: You're welcome! Just to clarify, it is not required to declare it as an array, as doing `$example[]` will implicitly create `$example` as an array. However, it is my preference and a general best-practice to define variables before you use them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare example as an array as well to get a 2-dimensional array and then append to it.

```
$example = array();
$example[] = array("first" => "Bob", "last" => "Smith", "address" => "123 Spruce st" ); # appends to array $example
$example[] = array("first" => "Sara", "last" => "Blask", "address" => "5678 Maple ct" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `$example` on both lines.  You need a multi-dimensional "array of arrays:"

```
$examples = array();
$examples[] = array("first" ...
$examples[] = array("first" ...

foreach ($examples as $example) {
   foreach ($example as $key => $value) { ...
```

Of course, you can also do the `printf` immediately instead of assigning the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to make an array of your arrays and loop through the main array:

```
<?php

$examples[] = array("first" => "Bob", "last" => "Smith", "address" => "123 Spruce st" );
$examples[] = array("first" => "Sara", "last" => "Blask", "address" => "5678 Maple ct" );

foreach ($examples as $example) {
  printf("<p>hello my name is %s %s and i live at %s</p>",$example['first'],$example['last'], $example['address']);
}

?>
```